# Laws concerning damages from car accident

Tags: halacha, torts-damages

I was recently in a car accident (BH no injuries). The accident was not my fault, and the person that hit my car is refusing to pay for the damage on my car and for a loan car (I only have one car). The person that hit me also asked me to not go through insurance (and refused to give me his insurance info). I mentioned that there is halacha on property damages, and he claims there are none. Can anyone point to specific sources? (the more the better).

I looked through Shulchan Aruch, but I got the gist that it was mainly about laws concerning a yid and non-jew. Its been over three months of constant back and forth.

Comment: Hi and welcome to MY! We won't be able to give you personalised advice, but you may start reading here: https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/4298028/jewish/Chapter-183-The-Laws-of-Property-Damages.htm

Comment: I was reading it, but I thought it wasnt specific enough since it was mainly about indirect damages

Comment: If you want specific things (and a ruling), you should definitely ask a competent rabbi!

Comment: There are hundreds of pages of the gemarra on property damages. See, for example, all of Masechet Bava Kamma. You need to see a rabbi and set up an appt at the Beit Din immediately.

Comment: Remember you two aren't in charge of understanding and applying the laws here. Go to a court and they will decide who owes what to whom.

Comment: There may well be laws requiring reporting accidents to the insurance company - see https://legaldictionary.net/car-accident/#:~:text=When%20a%20person%20is%20involved%20in%20a%20car,for%20the%20accident%2C%20and%20held%20liable%20for%20damages.

Comment: Check with your local bais din as they may give you permission to have your insurance company find out who his insurance company is and submit a claim.

Comment: Note that you need to do this at once as not filing a claim could prejudice your case. Als, is your car drivable?

Answer (score 1):

You will need a competent rabbi but if you take a look at [Cases in Monetary Halachah, Spitz, p 37-38](https://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781578195985.html) you will have valuable background.

He deals with a case of Shimon's brand-new car being damaged by Reuven. Shimon wants a new car of similar value to the original and a temporary vehicle until the replacement is available.

In summary, Rav Spitz writes that Reuven must cover all repair costs and the loss of value of the car after repair compared to before. The damaged car remains in Shimon's possession. Reuven does not have to provide a car for interim use.

Sources quoted by the author are Sh O, Ch M 403, 1-3.

Comment: "Must cover all repair costs" - agree.  "And the loss of value of the car after repair compared to before" - disagree.

Comment: @pcoz are you disagreeing with R Spitz or with the accuracy of the OPs summary?

Comment: @DoubleAA I am disagreeing with Rabbi Spitz on the grounds that the loss of market value to the car is *gerama* and not direct *hezek*.